# Kernel and properties

Tags: linear-algebra

It is a very simple question and I try to do it but I do not Succeed

Let $V$ be a vector space.

Let $T\colon V \to V$ a linear map

Assuming $\ker T^{i}= \ker T^{i+1}$ I need to proof that

$\ker T^{i+1} = \ker T^{i+2}$

So the first part is easy because for every vector $v$ in $\ker T^{i+1}$ we know that

$T^{i+2}(v)=T(T^{i+1}v)=T(0_V)=0_V$

but how do I do the other side.

How do I proof that ?

Thanks in advanced !!

Answer (score 3):

Assume that $T^{i+2}(v)=0$. Then $T^{i+1}(T(v))=0$, which means that $T(v)\in\ker T^{i+1}=\ker T^{i}$. That is $T^{i}(T(v))=0$ or, equivalently $T^{i+1}(v)=0$.

Answer (score 2):

If $\ker(T^{i+1})=\ker(T^i)$, then $$\ker(T^{i+2})=\{v\in V:Tv\in\ker(T^{i+1})\}=\{v\in V:Tv\in\ker(T^i)\}=\ker(T^{i+1}).$$

Answer (score 2):

Here's a hint to get you started: Suppose $v$ is in $Ker(T^{i+2})$. This means

$$ 0 = T^{i+2}(v) = T^{i+1} (T(v)) $$

and so $T(v)$ is in $ker(T^{i+1})$. Now use your assumption...